# removing a space in bibitem with url

Tags: urls

I need help with this spacing problem in 'thebibliography' environment. I have got a long url, which I need to put on a single line, but if I put some words before that, it creates a huge spaces between the words and the url. 
The problem seems to disappear after I remove '//' or '\newline' to create a new line.

How should I solve this problem within this environment?
Thanks a lot!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%these packages are not important

\begin{document}


 \begin{thebibliography}{12}{}

 \bibitem{1}Hà Duy Nghĩa \\
  Dostupné z :\url{http://www.mathvn.com/2012/08/ung-dung-ly-thuyet-ong-du-trong-cac-bai.html}


 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You should load the `hyperref` package *last* rather than first, and you should also load the `url` package with the option `hyphens`, to allow line-breaks at any `-` characters inside the URL string.

A separate issue: use `\par` rather than `\\` to generate a line break inside the `\bibitem` block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package *last*, not first

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{12}

\bibitem{1}Hà Duy Nghĩa 
  Dostupné z :\par\url{http://www.mathvn.com/2012/08/ung-dung-ly-thuyet-ong-du-trong-cac-bai.html}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly for this example, but why when I put this link (http://www.promys.org/sites/promys.org/files/assets/Problems\%202015.pdf) the same problem will arise again?

Comment: @TheMinhTran - The link appears to be broken. Please re-post. Or, just edit your original posting to show the code you're really trying to get typeset properly.

Comment: I am sorry: [link] (http://www.promys.org/sites/promys.org/files/assets/Problems%202015.pdf)

Comment: @TheMinhTran - The link you provided now points to a 3-page text file with no bibliography, and no bad line breaks. What am I supposed to be looking for?

Comment: yeah, what I meant was that if I replace this link with the link I used before, the same problem as the one in the picture will arise again..

Comment: @TheMinhTran - You've completely lost me. What is the connection between the pdf file that may be accessed via the hyperlink you've provided and the original problem, which was about a bibliography item with a bad line break?

Comment: Dont worry about it but thanks a lot anyway!!

Comment: @TheMinhTran - Very sorry I couldn't help more effectively.

Comment: Dont need to sorry, you have helped me massively. It was me who wasnt clear on the follow-up question..:D